# Whats the process for erasing disk, reinstalling Mac OS and restoring data and apps

Tags: macos, mac, time-machine, reinstall

I was told by the Apple genius bar that my OS was messed up and is slowing down my macbook.  I was told to erase the disk, reinstall the OS and restore the apps and data from my Time Machine.

I'm pretty sure I know how to erase the disk and reinstall the OS but when it comes to restoring from the Time Machine, what exactly do I restore?  I can restore all my major folders on my hard disk (users, Applications, Library etc.) but if I restore the System folder won't that overwrite the OS I just installed?

Secondly, I'm assuming all my apps will be reinstalled once I restore and that I won't have to reinstall those manually.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not comfortable doing a fresh install, you might consider getting another appointment with the Genius Bar. That said, it's not that complicated. Mashable has a pretty good [overview for  Mavericks](http://mashable.com/2013/10/23/clean-install-os-x-mavericks/), but the process is similar for the more recent OS X releases.

Once your machine is freshly rebuilt, create the same username you used on your previous install and you should be able to restore your personal files from a viable Time Machine backup. If you want to be extra cautious, you could create a temporary user, like 'admin' and restore all your original users and data as you like.

Comment: Link rot possible,. Please add whatever is in that link to the post (assuming you have the rights to copy it)

Comment: It was pretty simple.  After the reinstall of the OS (Mavericks) it asked me if I wanted to restore Apps and Data and gave me an option to restore from Time Machine.  Didn't have to set up usernames and all that.  They were preserved.